# uiitem.WaitForControlExist(milliseconds); Waits too long

Tags: testing, visual-studio-2012, automated-tests, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests

When I use the method uiitem.WaitForControlExist(milliseconds); Execution waits too long. Muchmore of the specified parameter.

Any idea?

Just an example on UIMap.cs file:

```
public void AnyAlertClickNo(int seconds)
{
    #region Variable Declarations
    WinWindow uIAlert = this.UIAlertWindow;
    WinButton uINoButton = this.UIAlertWindow.UIAnswerPanel.UINoButton;
    #endregion

    if(uIAlert.WaitForControlExist(seconds*1000)){
        Mouse.Click(uINoButton, new Point(20, 10));
    }

}
```

Te calls could be:

```
Any_UIMap aaa = new Any_UIMap();
aaa.AnyAlertClickNo(3);
```

I don't know why this code are waiting for this alert arround 15-20 seconds.

thanks in advance

Comment: Editing the question to give more details of the problem is good. You should also add details of what research you have done into finding a solution to the problem. My answer suggested some areas for you to investigate. What did you learn from following those suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The code is unlikely to be

```
uiitem.WaitForControlExist(milliseconds);
```

There are often several levels of UI control, so the code is more likely to be of the form:

```
UiMap.uiOne.uiTwo.uiThree.WaitForControlExist(milliseconds);
```

A line like the above has a meaning like the following, provided that it has the first use of the three UI controls:

```
var one = UiMap.uiOne.Find();
var two = one.uiTwo.Find();
two.uiThree.WaitForControlExist(milliseconds);
```

I suspect that your Coded UI test is spending some time on the `...Find()` calls. You might do some diagnostics to check where the time is spent. Look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/02/01/guidelines-on-improving-performance-of-coded-ui-test-playback.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dave_froslie/archive/2012/08/10/why-do-my-coded-ui-tests-pause-during-playback.aspx) for some good ideas on speeding up Coded UI tests.

Answer (score 0):

Well it is supposed to. 
[UITestControl.WaitForControlExist Method (Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee823124%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> > When the wait operation causes an implicit search for the control or, when the application is busy, the actual wait time could be more than the time-out specified.